# Qual o termo correto para "Stack overflow", é "Estouro de pilha" ou "Transbordamento de Pilha"?

Tags: debate

O chat do Stackoverflow-pt recebe o título de "Estouro de Pilha" está correto?

Quando penso em "estouro" imagino que as partes foram para todos os lados, e creio que não é o caso.

Comment: Acho que são sinônimos. Se você levar ao pé da letra "estourar" significa isso que você disse, mas existem outros casos onde ele se mostra sinônimo de "transbordamento", que nem quando se estoura o limite do cartão por exemplo, suas dívidas não foram espalhadas mundo afora, você só não pode mais continuar gastando, rs..

Comment: @Math saquei, é que "overflow" em nenhum momento (que eu saiba), remete a "estouro",no sentido da tradução mesmo  e sim a :alagar, inundar,derramamento e etc... Talvez se fosse Stack"burst", Stack"explosion", Stack"pop",,,Apesar que do ponto de vista que "estouro" pudesse fazer alusão à "Ultrapassou o limite" poderia ser...Vou refletir..x)

Comment: Mas quando alguma coisa transborda, ela se vai para todos os lados também, claro se o `container` tiver a "tampa" regular hehe :b

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade Nesse caso apenas o excedido, no caso do estouro a pilha toda vai pelo ar...Acho que o transbordamento não danifica o cantainer, o estouro "estóra tudo"...kkk

Comment: É muito **preciosismo**, querer levar tudo ao pé da letra.

Comment: "every cloud has a silver lining" :D

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Tudo é muita coisa, num cabe na sua frase...

Comment: Pode ser porque eu sou velho mas, na faculdade quando aprendemos sobre gerência de memória, o nome da falha em português era "estouro de pilha", ou "estouro de memória", foi por isso que usei como nome do chat `;)`

Comment: @Gabe hehe... Na verdade andei pesquisando e vi que em linguagens como C é bem comum esse termo, então.... Tá respondida minha dúvida...Grato pela "preciosa" delicadeza, em responder a novatos...

Comment: @MagicHat Responder aos novatos é o propósito do site haha

Comment: @Gabe não sei se o termo "velho" se aplica a pessoas como vc... Por mais idade que tenha... x)

Comment: @Gabe por acaso eu pensei que o nome do chat era uma ironia na tradução...

Comment: [Como posso traduzir «stack overflow»?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/3345/153)

Comment: Falando em preciosismo, o próprio termo _stack overflow_, que é um caso especial de _buffer overflow_ (dependendo de como é implementado pelo menos), não é muito exato, pois o transbordamento em si não chega a ocorrer; no momento em que está prestes a ocorrer (ou seja, prestes a invadir memória não requisitada) o sistema dispara uma _segmentation fault_. Mais exato seria algo como _stack limit reached_ ou _stack overflow attempt_.